# How can create Semi Circle Donut in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to design the following cycle bar of BMI (Body Mass Index) in Android:

[image: for vki calculator]

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) where you control the rendering of each of those elements.

Comment: But I can not create have a axample ?

Comment: Follow the link I posted. The documentation shows you how to create a custom view. If that's not enough, simply searching for "Android Custom View" should give you plenty of examples.